# How to ask if a number is subdivison of an another number in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new in Java, I would like to know how can I ask if a number is subdivision of an another number in Java?

For ex. Is 5 subdivision of 10? That is..

Thank you!

Comment: You would begin by 1) making sure you understand the problem; and 2) writing some code. We're not here to write your code for you -- you should at least make *some* attempt to solve your own problem before asking for help.

Comment: Do you mean "factor" when you're saying "subdivision?"  Do you want to know if 5 is a factor (or divisor) of 10?

Comment: @IanMcLaird yeah Divisor*

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about modular arithmetic:

```
if (10 % 5 == 0) {
    System.out.println("5 divides 10");
}
```

If you want to define a method to do this:

```
public static boolean divides(int a, int b) {
    return a % b == 0;
}
```

Comment: More accurate output would be "5 divides 10", or "10 is divisible by 5".